# Error in colab in finding directory and file

Tags: keras, google-colaboratory

```
img = load_img('train/cat/cat.12499.jpg')
```

I'm using colab with the same code that I used in Jupyter, but now I get the below error, although the directory and file there are in:

No such file or directory: 'train/cat/cat.12499.jpg'

I copied the directory in google drive!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved with these commands

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

and I've modified the code in this way:

```
img = load_img("drive/My Drive/app/train/cat/cat.12499.jpg")  # t
```